# c#: remove brackets of certain size if existing including its content

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract strings from a huge database. Sometimes (not always) these strings contain a kind of serial number at the end, which I would like to remove. The serial number has always the same appearance, e.g.:

```
string text = "176 - monoring_01 (xktz) (bd685448-c2cf-4433-az87-8ebc9be5ae56)"
```

I would like to get only the "176 - monoring_01 (xktz)" part and remove the serial number including its brackets.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017.

That's what I tried:

```
if (text.Contains(@" ?\(.{36}\)"))                                
            {                                                                       
               text_m = Regex.Replace(text, @" ?\(.*?\)", string.Empty);  
            else
            {                                                                       
                text_m =text;                                             
            }
```

But I always get the full strings. So, I tried:

```
Console.WriteLine(text.Contains(@" ?\(.{36}\)"));
```

And indeed the output is 'false', so it doesn't recognize the brackets between the 36 digits.
What's wrong here?

Comment: Contains doesn't use regex, you should use Regex.IsMatch() for that

Comment: Also, I'd recommend to use the same regex in your replacement as the one you use in your match, or you could be surprised ;).
Btw, you don't event need to test with a if, the regex.Replace will not replace anything if doesn't match

Comment: `string.Contains` does not accept a regex, use `Regex.IsMatch(string, pattern)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `string.Contains()` doesn't use regex (that's why you found the results confusing)

2) The `if` test isn't even necessary, the `Regex.Replace` will replace only the matches. If no match, no replacement.

So, you can change all your code block with :

```
text_m = Regex.Replace(text, @" ?\(.{36}\)", string.Empty);
```

I'd even write a slightly more restrictive regex : `@" ?\([^\(\)]{36}\)"` (don't allow any parenthesis inside the matched ones!), just as a safety net, if your strings become more diverse.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex.Match
eg

```cs
  text = text.Replace(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(text, @" ?\(.{36}\)").ToString(), "");
```

output

```
176 - monoring_01 (xktz)
```

Answer (score 0):

If indeed, all the records the same pattern, e.g 1 space and a serial inside brackets, you can use `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` methods. Something Like:

```
string text = "176 - monoring_01 (xktz) (bd685448-c2cf-4433-az87-8ebc9be5ae56)";
var index = text.LastIndexOf("(");
string result = text.Substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if your serial is always at the end, 36-cgars-long and between parentheses:

```
str = str.Trim();

bool containsSerial = str[str.Length-1] == ')' && str[str.Length-38] == '(';

if (containsSerial)
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 38);
```